# Finding a value in a multi select list parameter in report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a multi select input parameter for a report.

We know how to find whether a values is present in that parameter or not by using

```
$X{IN, colName, paramName}
```

the above expression in WHERE condition clause.

That is working fine.

But how will we find whether a variable ( let say having value 3 ) is present in parameter ( same multi select list let say [ 1, 2 ,3, 5] ) or not.

By validating the above condition i want to display something in report's static text field.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `But how will we find whether a variable ( let say having value 3 ) is present in parameter ( same multi select list let say [ 1, 2 ,3, 5] ) or not.` What is the type of parameter and so on?

Comment: Suppose if we have multi select list parameter as clientlist having labeles client1 , client2 , client3 , client4 ,client5 and values as 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. Now we can filter the rows from table at the sql query level. Now what i want is if i want to display a static text field based on client id value then Can we do a search over the parameter list like we did at the sql query level ?? I hope i make sense. If it is not clear please let me know.

Comment: One solution is check for each index in the list like the following.                     (Integer.parseInt($P{clientparameter}.get(0)) == 4 ) but this is a very lengthy process and if the client list is big then print when expression in ireport designer is not taking too lengthy expression...

Comment: What is the type of parameter? List or String or something else?

Comment: as the parameter is multi select list.. the type will be List.

Comment: In this case you can use [List.contains(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method. Something like this: `$P{listParam}.contains("3")`

Comment: Thx Alex. It is working as expected now.